# The type or namespace name 'ApiVersionDescription' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, aspnet-api-versioning

I already added the package of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer, but I'm still getting this error. Is anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?Thank you in advance.

Reference: https://www.meziantou.net/versioning-an-asp-net-core-api.htm#integration-with-ope

Comment: did you try installing this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/

Comment: Hi, @jayz, please provide more details of error so that we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said which versions or runtimes you are targeting. I'm going to assume that your project is .NET Core 3.1 or newer and the language is C#. The `ApiVersionDesription` class is defined in **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer.dll**. The following are required to resolve this error message:

1. Reference the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer** NuGet package
2. *Use* the corresponding namespace with `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;`

You said you've already done #1 so I presume the only issue is #2. If you did not add the reference using tooling, it's worth double-checking that the NuGet package is properly referenced and the containing assembly was also added as a reference.

You also did not mention what your end goal was. 99% of the scenarios that use the API Explorer extensions for API Versioning want to wire up Swashbuckle or some other Open API/Swagger document generator. I would consider reviewing the official [API Versioning Swagger Example](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/ms/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample) for ASP.NET Core and cross-reference it with your configuration. It is a working end-to-end solution and *should* help reveal the step or steps that you're missing.

---

UPDATE: If you're using ASP.NET API Versioning >= 6.0.0 then the correct:

- Package is [Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer](https://nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer)
- Namespace is `Asp.Versioning.ApiExplorer`
- Example is now [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/main/examples/AspNetCore/WebApi/OpenApiExample)